# Operator '<' and multiple values with get function, not returning

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I want to work with operator '<' but I don't know what could be the solution for this one. I want to make
an action of operator '<' (which type is boolean) that compares a volume of two boxes. How do I get this result?

I also don't know how to return multiple values in function GetBox(), how do I solve it? I want to individually return width, height and depth.

Here is the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Box{
    private:
    int width;
    int height;
    int depth; 
    public:
    
    Box():width(0),height(0),depth(0){};
    
    Box(int w, int h, int d):width(w),height(h),depth(d){};
    
    void BoxVolume();
    void SetBox(int w1,int h1,int d1);
    int GetBox();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &exit,const Box &A);
    Box operator<(Box&);
    
};
void Box::SetBox(int w1,int h1,int d1){
    width=w1;
    height=h1;
    depth=d1;
}
int Box::GetBox(){
    return width,height,depth;
}
void Box::BoxVolume(){
    cout<<"Volume: "<<width*height*depth<<endl;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream &exit, const Box &B){
    Box temp2;
    exit<<B.width<<" "<<B.height<<" "<<B.depth<<" "<<endl;
    return exit; 
}

Box Box::operator<(Box &K){
    
}
int main(){
    Box Box1;
    cout<<"Details about first box:"<<endl;
    Box1.SetBox(1,3,5);
    Box1.GetBox();
    cout<<Box1;
    Box1.BoxVolume();
    cout<<endl;
    
    Box Box2;
    cout<<"Details about second box:"<<endl;
    Box2.SetBox(2,4,6);
    Box2.GetBox();
    cout<<Box2;
    Box2.BoxVolume();
}
```

Comment: Returning a `Box` from `operator <` instead of `true` or `false` doesn't make sense.

Comment: From which function do you want to return multiple values? The ways to solve this might be different.

Comment: Please explain what you want `operator<` to *mean* for a `Box`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen look at his GetBox method.

Comment: Oh, right. `std::array<int, 3>` as the return type would be an option, but at this point why don't you just make `width`, `height` and `depth` public? These members are already exposed.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen good point, they are exposed, my bad.. Then my get and set functions make no sense right? I think linking them with a structure would be better idea? But how do I do that exactly? Need a little help about this.

Comment: @cigien I want operator< for comparing volume of the first box and volume of the second box, if comparison is correct return true and if it's not return false, what is the closest solution for that?

Comment: The answer below seems to do what you want. I'm not clear why/where you want to return multiple values?

Comment: @cigien I wanted to put width, height and depth in GetBox() and try to do with a structure/object which unites them and then return that structure/object, but I'm not sure how to exactly do that.

Comment: I would say, write a structure that has those fields, but `Box` already does that. Why not return a `Box` from `GetBox`?

Comment: @cigien it seems pretty logical to me yeah, but which parameters shall I use? I just keep getting errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, operator< should return boolean and thus the function signature should be:

`bool operator<(const Box &other) const;`

If you want to compare volumes, you shold create a function, which returns computed volume:

`int getVolume() const { return width * height * depth; }`

With that, you can easily implement the comparator function:

```
bool Box::operator<(const Box &other) const {
    return getVolume() < other.getVolume();
}
```

And no, you cannot return more than a single value from a function. If you want to do that, you need to define a structure containing multiple values and return instance of that structure instead.

Comment: I wanted to return individually width, height and depth so it seems I have to do with a structure? 
I will try this comparison and I will let you know if I have any further questions.

Comment: If you want to return these individually, it is best to implement getWidth, getHeight and getDepth methods. While it may be tempting to do everything with just a single line of code, it actually cripples code readability in most use cases.

Comment: Yeah it is very impractical to use the get method for each size separately, can you update this GetBox method with a structure for width, height and depth? And then returning that structure for all of 3 values. I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Why? What is more practical in doing:

```auto dimensions = box.GetBox();
int width = dimensions.width;```

over this?
```int width = box.getWidth();```

You are requesting something that would actually complicate your code.

Comment: To be clear, there is NO way to achieve Pythonic: ```w, h, d = box.getDimensions();```